# Self Learning (pgfplots, asymptote) in systematic manner from ab initio

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, diagrams, asymptote, tikz-pic

Kindly guide in order to self learn in a systematic manner the following

1. Pgfplots
2. Asymptote

for 2D and 3D drawings.

Thanks

Comment: `texdoc pgfplots` and `texdoc asymptote` (?)

Comment: I tried to search google but texdocs are not opening.

Comment: Ah, you should write those commands in cmd/Command Prompt (Windows) or Terminal (Linux). 

Comment: May be too ignorant if any comprehensive tutorial in PDF form.

Comment: Try [this here link](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf) to the PGF-Manual written by the creator of PGF-Tikz. It contains a number of Tutorials at the beginning of the document showing you the most commonly used features of Tikz.

Comment: Thank you any link for asymptote as well.

Comment: When you load the package, you usually get the manual as well.  You just have to find it. If anything, these manuals have too many tutorials.

Comment: Thank you for the info.

Comment: @RajaAliRiaz study this link https://asymptote.sourceforge.io/ Asymptote manual https://asymptote.sourceforge.io/asymptote.pdf Asymptote tutorial https://asymptote.sourceforge.io/asymptote_tutorial.pdf

Comment: Thank you very much